# How to remove path info?

Tags: php, filepath

I need to remove "../upload" so it would just the filename only, how to do that.
like the image below:

[image: want to delete ..]

Here's my code,

```
$target_dir    = "../uploads/";
  $target_file       = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']);
  $fileOK      = 1;
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  if ($fileOK == 0) {
    echo "File cant upload";
  } else {
    if (copy($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
      echo "File Error";
    }
  }
```

Here's the image after add str_replace,

[image]

Insert code to database:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tb_master(`kode` ,`nama` ,`target_file`)VALUES ('$kode','$nama','$target_file')";
```

Comment: this code generate that list ???

Comment: that's not a list, its a record.. @PouyaDarabi

Comment: your code print something like this "The file .... has been uploaded." , but in picture , i cant see any of them!

Comment: str_replace work but the record that save in db still has "../uploads/" @PouyaDarabi

Comment: add your db insert code to question!

Comment: you can insert just file name in your db by replace '$targetfile' with  basename( $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]) or you can use str_replace("../uploads/",str) in function that make list for u

Answer (score 0):

you can do a str_replace

```
echo "The file ". basename(str_replace("../uploads/","",$_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

You search for "../uploads/" in the $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'] string and replace it with "" (nothing). This will return just the filename only. If you want to remove it without the extension mayI suggest you look at a regex to match anything after the . and remove it.

Hope this answers your question, it is awfully vague.

Comment: Thank you for ur quick answer. but when i try str_replace, it doesn't work. still show like the image above. @duenna